How to Export face spreadsheet with named attribute created from geometry nodes?
From what I understood from searching online, you don't have any way to export the spreadsheet as CSV, so you have to do some workaround with python scripting. Well, that's not ideal but I managed to export a CSV of points coordinate. However I can't find how to access named attribute of a face with bpy.
I tried looking into bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph). ... it has "vertices" and "edges" attribut but no "faces" so I have no idea where I should look.
For reference :this is very close from what I want to do, but I want to loop over faces, not vertices.
Context : for educational purpose i have a very basic rendering engine where meshes are stored as a list of points (xyz) and a list of faces (only triangle, thus a face is stored as 3 integers representing the index of the points in the points list. If you can write the representation of a tetrahedron or a cube by hand anything more complex is way too tedious so I tried automating the process with blender. I have a simple geometry node that does the trick : 

Well last ressort solution for me would be to split edges, and store faces index in vertices and after that re-parse the text file to reconstruct faces. Or another solution would be to screen the spreadsheet and feed the image into a character recognition program but seriously that sounds like too much bother for something as simple as exporting a csv.

Hi. If you just change the attr_names in the accepted answer to the linked question then the script exports these face attributes. The faces are in mesh.polygons. Is this your question?

just tried, it works ! Thank you, my bad, I should've try to understand more the script it was really polyvalent.

Edit : as @blunder mentioned, this post covers my problem
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/318588/how-to-export-a-blender-spreadsheet-information-into-a-csv-and-txt-file
Edit I'm sorry for being a stackexchange noob but I literally cannot find how to mark as answer.

You can't mark a comment as an answer, however you can post an answer to your own question.

Great that it worked. I voted to mark this question as a duplicate so it can be linked and closed.
